# Exponential Discounting of Cash Flows

Tags: finance, discounting

I wonder for exponential discounting method to do the discount cash flow, may I doing it right as the following screenshot from Excel, assuming the discount rate is 4%?

Thanks!

[image]

[image]

Comment: Why \$G\$8-C\$8 ? Shouldn't just be C\$8 ?

Comment: That's the part where I'm confused about, because it says tn = the time until the nth cash flow.

Comment: The cash flows that are close to the present in time have to be discounted only a little, those that are far in time have to be discounted (reduced in value) more. You seem to be doing the opposite.

Comment: Then I suppose the following will be how it should be done?            http://imgur.com/a/48ZX7

Comment: In discrete time with discrete compounding, the formula for the discount factor should be, using your notation: $\frac{1}{(1+r(t_n))^{t_n}}$.

Answer (score 2):

Then I suppose the following will be how it should be done?

[image]